# Non matching end-tag

Tags: jsf, xhtml, jstl

I have the following code in my xhtml page:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${menu}">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:startsWith(item.key, 'startDropdown.')}">
      <c:set var="dropdown" scope ="session" value="true" />
      <c:set var="dropdownnaam" scope ="session" value="${fn:substringAfter(item.key, 'startDropdown.')}" />
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a id="${dropdownnaam}" href="#" role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">#{i18nTeksten.tekst(item.value)}<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center" aria-labelledby="${dropdownnaam}">
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${item.key.equals('endDropdown')}">
      <c:set var="dropdown" scope ="session" value="false"/>
              </div>
            </li>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${dropdown.equals('true')}">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#{item.key}">#{i18nTeksten.tekst(item.value)}</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#{item.key}">#{i18nTeksten.tekst(item.value)}</a></li>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

When it is used I get the following error:

> Error Traced[line: 29] The element type "div" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

When I remove the following lines (8-10)

```
</c:when>
<c:when test="${item.key.equal('endDropdown')}">
  <c:set var="dropdown" scope ="session" value="false"/>
```

then everything works fine (I do not use the 'dropdown' feature yet). I suppose that this has to do with the way that the xhtml is parsed.

Is there a (simple/standard) way to resolve/bypass this problem or is it better to put this logic in a Java class on the server?

Answer (score 1):

If

```
<c:when test="${item.key.equal('endDropdown')}">
```

is false, then there is not end `div`

maybe you want to move it to after `</c:when>`

or provide another `when` tag for when the above is `false`

Comment: You are right that this might happen. But this is not always the case at the end of the parsing. In my test this was certainly not the case.

Comment: But how can the compiler know that?  Your data may prevent it from happening but other data may cause the `div` to be openeded in `<c:when test="${fn:startsWith(item.key, 'startDropdown.')}">` and not closed in `<c:when test="${item.key.equal('endDropdown')}">`

Comment: So (how) can I fool the compiler? There is no `startDropdown.` or `endDropdown` in my current test data. I am doing a backwards compatibility test before I start to implement the dropdown implementation. Can I somehow see the generated html that caused this error?

Comment: The error happens before generating the html. It is in fact invalid XML (which xhtml conforms to).

Comment: Marco, how about looping through `items="${menu}"` and just collect the information e.g. `if (has startDropdown) <c:set var="startDropdown" value="true" />` `if (has endDropdown) <c:set var="endDropdown" value="true" />`  and then after the loop decode if you need to diaply or not